# Safari background-image issue

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm building a Grid with background images but things go wrong in Safari.
(Safari 7, 6 and 5, tested in Browserstack )

This is the website. As you can see in Chrome, FF or IE there's a grid with background image set inline.

http://fourseasonsrally.com/1

In Safari I sometimes see the background image but then it suddenly disappears.. I could not reproduce the error in other browsers.

This is what the grid looks like on chrome

[image]

#### UPDATE 1: Shorthand CSS

It seems that shorthand css is ignored by Safari, I removed all the shorthand properties but the problem persists.

Any idea what might be going wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean header logo (FOURSEASONS RALLY) not visible in safari - changes the below css.

present css:

```
    .header {
     background: url("../img/logo.svg") no-repeat scroll center center / contain #111;
    }
```

remove the " / contain"

```
      .header {
     background: url("../img/logo.svg") no-repeat scroll center center #111;
    }
```

Comment: It is written on a seperate line in my .css

Comment: Add  "background-color: #000;" css in ".header" class

Comment: I did that thank you, but the real problem is the grid where all the background images are being overwritten